# CSS gradient background color not working, turning into grey on table header

Tags: css, gradient, background-color

I have a table and customized with CSS, all well..

Solid color works fine..

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color:#32cd80;
color:#000000
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/20v000ax/ as you can see it's green now

---

Now here the problem comes, after customizing it with green gradient color, I see a grey instead.

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
     background: rgba(122, 255, 82, 1);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1) 100%);
     background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1)));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1) 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1) 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1) 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(122, 255, 82, 1) 0%, rgba(50, 205, 205, 1) 100%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7aff52', endColorstr='#32cdcd', GradientType=1);
     color:#000000
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/20v000ax/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written over on line 63 by:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
   background-image: url("img/bg.png");
}
```

and after that on line 73 by:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
   background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5rUFJ8h.png");
}
```

Here's an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20v000ax/4/)**.

I've added a `span` inside `.header` for those arrows.

```
table.tablesorter thead tr span {
   display: block;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
 table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp span {
     background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/X1GzAnN.png);
 }
 table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown span {
     background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/5rUFJ8h.png);
 }
```

And I gave an `gradient` **id** for the same `header`, because it's all about **[css specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg)**:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp,
table.tablesorter thead tr #gradient {
     ...
 }
```

So now the `th` looks like this:

```
    <th id="gradient" class="header headerSortDown"><span>Car</span></th>
```

Comment: That works.. but could you make the header text center align and the arrows on far right?

Comment: That's simple! Add: `padding: 3px 6px;`  to `th` on line 21.

Answer (score 0):

modify the CSS Code  like this

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr {
background-color: #32cd80;
color: #000000;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue);
background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

modify below class

```
  table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
 color: #000000;
}
```

[workking fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/20v000ax/6/)

the problem is  **background** and **background-image** both are same class like **margin** 
,**margin-right**.
that why one  class *(background:)*  class overwrite the another one same class(*background-image:)*

[image]

Comment: clicking on the header the color changes to solid.

Comment: table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
     border:1px solid #ffffff;
 } please update this class.and i updated in jsfiddel also please check @skyline33